# Change mode-line size without changing header line

Tags: faces, mode-line, header-line

There are several posts and information around for changing the mode-line face properties, like size. I tried them for a smaller mode-line, using:

`(set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil  :height 100)`

This works fine, but I've just realized that this also changes the top (header?) line that I use for `sticky-func-mode`, which is unfortunate because it is smaller than my buffer face and disrupts the visual structure of the code.

How can I change the mode-line size without affecting the header line (I'm not sure how its called)?

Comment: There are really just too many possibilities to give an answer here.  The `mode-line-format` can be set to something completely different than the `header-line-format`.  By default they may share some of the same components, but each one can be customized independently.  The text within each can be without any specific faces, or they can have many different faces assigned.  You could conceivably spend some time and completely customize the `header-line-format` in `sticky-func-mode` to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found it; doing an apropos of header-line and searching for faces put me on the right track. For example:

`(set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil  :height 100)
(set-face-attribute 'header-line nil  :height 200)`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this general solution, but it will not work when certain textual components of the `mode-line-format` or `header-line-format` contain different faces (with different heights/sizes) and/or images.