# Effect of doom themes in tabulated list header line is visually confusing

Tags: themes, header-line, proced

I am on the process of moving from prelude [1] to a stand-alone config I have created from scratch [2], though by largely copying other people's `.emacs`. It seems I have inadvertently changed the rendering of the header line in tabulated mode [3], but I am struggling to find out how to configure this correctly. When using prelude, instances of tabulated mode are rendered like so (using `doom-dark+` theme):

[image: proced with tabulated mode right rendering]

However, in my new .emacs I now get the following:

[image: proced with tabulated mode wrong rendering]

It appears I am now "overriding" the rendering of the header line somehow, but I am unsure as to what is causing this. Any pointers would be very helpful.

[1] https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude

[2] https://github.com/mcraveiro/cunene

[3] https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/emacs-lisp/tabulated-list.el

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't completely solved this problem, but I have found more details and a workaround. The gist of it is that doom-themes [1] appear to use the same face for the header-line as they do for the modeline, causing this visual confusion. There are several tickets open on this:

- [doom-challenger-deep: not enough contrast for header-line #320](https://github.com/hlissner/emacs-doom-themes/issues/320)
- [header-line should not inherit mode-line #473](https://github.com/hlissner/emacs-doom-themes/issues/473)

The workaround as per ticket #320 is:

```lisp
(face-spec-set 'header-line '((t :background "#23214b")))
```

However, as you can see from the screenshots above, prelude - or my prelude config, not sure just yet - was doing something clever and setting up this face to a more sensible value. I will continue investigating, but this at least makes the theme usable.

[1] https://github.com/hlissner/emacs-doom-themes

**Update**

Found a much better solution to this problem. On the Emacs with prelude, I did `customize-face` for face `header-line`. There you can see all the properties for the face. I then did `customize-face` for the same face using my new configuration file, and replicated the configuration I had in prelude, and saved it to my custom file. The generated lisp is as follows:

```lisp
(custom-set-faces
  ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(header-line ((t (:inherit mode-line :background "#2b2b2b" :foreground "#f0dfaf" :box (:line-width -1 :color "#585858" :style released-button))))))
```

I could't quite replicate the grey colour on the border of the box, so `#585858` is an approximation. However, the final result is very close:

[image: Header-line with new face]

FWIW, the options in custom were as follows:

[image: Custom properties]

Comment: See also [Change mode-line size without changing header line](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26386/change-mode-line-size-without-changing-header-line).